# How to execute logic on query?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

With transactions, we can put our business logic in the transaction processors. Very simple access control logic can be put in the ACL file. But how can we use more complex logic to guard (or extend) queries?

I'm working on a case where I'd like to restrict read access to an asset by checking if another asset exists and has a certain property.

Example:

```
asset PersonalDetails identified by id {
  o String id
  o String dateOfBirth
  o String firstName
  o String lastName
  --> Participant owner
}

asset AccessRequest identified by id {
  o String id
  o String property
  o Boolean allowed
  --> PersonalDetails personalDetails
}
```

When a participant requests PersonalDetails, an AccessRequest has to exist and to have allowed === true. The owner of the personal details is the one who can grant access. Ideally the AccessRequest has a field 'property' to allow more fine grained access control.

So my initial thought was:

```
transaction GetInfo identified by transactionId {
  o String transactionId
  --> AccessRequest accessRequest
}

/**
 * Sample transaction
 * @param {org.example.GetInfo} tx
 * @transaction
 */
function getInfo(tx) {
    if (!tx.accessRequest.allowed) {
        throw 'Access denied.';
    }
    return Promise.resolve(tx.accessRequest.personalDetails[tx.accessRequest.property]);
}
```

But I don't think Composer supports returning values from a transaction (right?). So, in general how can we use logic in or before queries and more specifically, what would be the 'composer way' to solve my case?

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the process of committing a new sample network that illustrates how to do this. You can follow the pull request here:
https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/pull/66/commits/6bb0d757a0248046da60b013cfddbd7d549686b6